# How to ignore errors in function execution within optim?

Tags: r, optimization

I am using `optim` to estimate parameters of a custom function. This custom function includes a function that produces an error message in case of invalid parameter input (it comprises multiple distributions, but assume for example that an error is produced if a negative standard deviation for a normal distribution occurs. So unlike the `NaN` value and warning of the `dnorm` function, this function stops and returns an error message).

Now, if I use the `BFGS` option in `optim`, then `optim` may at some point try invalid parameter inputs that will result in an error when evaluating the custom function and stop the optim procedure. This is not a problem if I use the `Nelder-Mead` option instead.

So, my question is: Is there any way to use the `optim` function with `BFGS` option such that it does not stop in case of errors of the custom function over which the optimization takes place?

Of course, I could theoretically re-write the custom function, but this is not an option as it is part of a larger package that requires the error messages in other cases. I am also aware of the `L-BFGS-B` option, however, the choice of suitable bounds for the parameters will not be straightforward in many cases (the actual values causing errors might be complex transformation of the training data).

Here is an example (Maximum Likelihood estimation of parameters of a standard normal distribution)

```
fn <- function(par, obs){
  if(par[2] < 0){stop("error msg")}
  return(sum(-dnorm(obs, mean = par[1], sd = par[2], log = TRUE)))
}

dat <- rnorm(100)

optim(par = c(1,2), fn = fn, obs = dat, method = "BFGS") # stops due to error message
optim(par = c(1,2), fn = fn, obs = dat, method = "Nelder-Mead") # works
optim(par = c(1,2), fn = fn, obs = dat, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(-10,0.001), upper = c(10,10)) # works
```

Comment: Which library are we using?

Comment: The package I am using is a very small R package with very few users. To stay anonymous, I would rather not refer to it since I am one of the very few users. Instead, I have added an example to my post that illustrates what I mean

Comment: I'm not sure if the idea of ignoring errors is a good one. I hope we are talking about *graceful error handling*, where you observe the error and proceed according to this status. I would be much better, to change your code so that no errors are produced (choosing the right optimizers for the data). If you want to stick to using these optimizers without beeing sure, that they will work, you should use **error-handling** within R. Someling like **tryCatch**.

Comment: Regarding general principles, I definitely agree. I was just wondering whether there is a way to use the `BFGS` method in a similar fashion as the `Nelder-Mead` method already handles the function errors inside `optim`.

Comment: What do you mean by ```handles the function error inside```. These are all heuristics and will sometimes struggle. ```BFGS``` is not ```Nelder-mead``` so they will show different error-behaviour! Sometimes Nelder-mead will fail, but BFGS will converge.

Comment: Maybe I do not know enough about how `BFGS` and `Nelder-Mead` actually work, I just assumed that `Nelder-Mead` is a gird-search algorithm that can simply ignore any input leading to errors, and continue searching.

Comment: Nelder-Mead is a simplicial algorithm, not a grid search. Sometimes you can get away with returning a large value when the current point cannot be evaluated.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Yes, that is essentially what I am doing now. However, it might not be so obvious how to do that, so I was wondering whether there might be an easier / more general way to "ignore" error messages

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the following approach :

```
fn <- function(par, obs, const = 10 ^ 30)
{
  if(par[2] < 0)
  {
    return(const)
    
  }else
  {
    logLik <- tryCatch(sum(-dnorm(obs, mean = par[1], sd = par[2], log = TRUE)), error = function(e) NA)
    
    if(is.na(logLik))
    {
      return(const)
      
    }else
    {
      return(logLik)
    }
  }
}

dat <- rnorm(100)

optim(par = c(1,2), fn = fn, obs = dat, method = "BFGS") # stops due to error message
```